# Wordpress Header is already sent js time interval function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am writing my page on wordpress. At one point I want to load my notification.php every time interval like for example first in 1 second and then 10 seconds. For that I use js function:

```
function loadNotification() {
    $("#randomtext").load("notification.php");
}
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       loadNotification();
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
                 loadNotification();
         }, 10000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

This code right there seems to be giving me error `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`. Though simply this:
`loadNotification();` doesn't.

I checked my code and deleted any unnecessary empty line or space. That didn't seem to fix my problem. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Not a client side issue. It's a server side issue. Enable output buffering.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't understand that that is nor how to do it. Can you explain?

Comment: Check out the dupe and read the answers... `:)`

Comment: Did that. I moved my script to the bottom and it seemed to fix my problem. Thank you.